# Proper way to obtain a std:string from a Pro*C/C++ VARCHAR

Tags: c++, oracle-pro-c

What is the proper way of getting a `std:string` out of a Pro*C/C++ `VARCHAR`?

```
VARCHAR some_column[10];

std::string x(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(some_column.arr), some_column.len);
std::string y((char const*) some_column.arr, some_column.len);
```

Comment: *g++ complains:* -- Please post the error message.

Comment: The first way is malformed, you are specifying `std::string` twice and missing a closing `)`. And in both ways, you don't need to cast to `const` since `some_column` is not `const` to begin with.  Either `std::string x(reinterpret_cast<char*>(some_column.arr), some_column.len);` or `std::string y((char*) some_column.arr, some_column.len);` *should* work just fine, based on [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58233/dev.htm#2885).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can't.

Read  it into a character array which is big enough to hold the value.
Add one additional character to the array size, and initialize it to 0, so that you have a c string.

After loading it, into the character buffer, assign it to the string.

Comment: You don't need to convert the buffer into a C-string. you can just tell `std::string` how large the buffer actually is when you assign it to the `std::string`. Also, if you know the needed buffer size in order to read the `varchar` into the buffer, then you could just eliminate the buffer altogether and resize the `std::string` instead and then read directly into its data memory.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you have any sample code that demonstrates the technique?

Comment: The 1st technique is demonstrated in the OP's question, as well as my [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77518599/77518716#comment136661796_77518599).  The 2nd technique would look like this: `std::string x(size, '\0'); read_varchar_into(x.data(), size);` where `read_varchar_into()` is whatever you want to use to read the varchar data into the character array.

Comment: Ah.  I interpreted it as reading it in via Pro*C.  I will do some experimentation with your technique.